# WordPress check if Sec-GPC value exists in HTTP Request Header

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

How can I detect if "Sec-GPC:1" exists in the HTTP Request Headers?

```
    <?PHP function detect_gpc_signal() {
    if (isset($_GET['Sec-Gpc'])) {
      echo 'GPC signal detected in GET data';
    } elseif (isset($_POST['Sec-Gpc'])) {
      echo 'GPC signal detected in POST data';
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['Sec-Gpc'])) {
      echo 'GPC signal detected in COOKIE data';
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER['Sec-Gpc'])) {
      echo 'GPC signal detected in SERVER data';
    } else {
      echo 'No GPC signal detected';
    }
} 
add_action('wp_footer', 'detect_gpc_signal'); ?>
```

Comment: You might try using [getallheaders()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) then check `isset` and `empty` for the specific header key.

Comment: Or something like that $request->get_header('Sec-Gpc'), [read more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/get_header/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fo suggesting getallheaders(). With your help, I figured out two methods, with and without Javascript.

```
/* Add GPC Banner to WP Header */
function display_gpc_signal_banner() {
echo '<section id="headerBannerGpc" class="bg-color"><div 
class="container detect-gpc-signal py-1 small"><span class="alert- 
circle"></span> Global Privacy Signal Detected</div></section>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'display_gpc_signal_banner');

// Detect GPC Signal with Javascript
function detect_gpc_signal_js() {
?>
  <script>
  if(navigator.globalPrivacyControl == true ) {
    // Add a class to the body tag -- This makes the GPC banner visible
    document.body.classList.add('gpc-signal-detected');
    document.getElementById('headerBannerGpc').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // Add a class to body tag declaring the GPC signal was not detected
    document.body.classList.add('no-gpc-signal-detected');
    document.getElementById('headerBannerGpc').style.display = "none";
  }
  </script>
  <?
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'detect_gpc_signal_js');

// Add a unique class to the body tag when GPC signal is detected
function detect_gpc_signal_body_class( $classes ) {
$headers = getallheaders();
if($headers['sec-gpc'] == 1) {
  $classes[] = 'gpc-signal-detected-no-js';
} else {
  $classes[] = 'no-gpc-signal-detected-no-js';
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'detect_gpc_signal_body_class' );
```

UPDATE

The original function works when HTTP_ is added to the value.

```
  if (isset($_GET['HTTP_SEC_GPC'])) {
  echo 'GPC signal detected in GET data';
  } elseif (isset($_POST['HTTP_SEC_GPC'])) {
  echo 'GPC signal detected in POST data';
  } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['HTTP_SEC_GPC'])) {
  echo 'GPC signal detected in COOKIE data';
  } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_GPC'])) {
  echo 'GPC signal detected in SERVER data';
  } else {
   echo 'No GPC signal detected';
  }
```